# Android BroadcastReceiver and killing process

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

let's assume we start a service from BrodcastReceiver on some broadcast. Can the process be killed after onReceive() returns and before service is started? And if so, how can this behavior be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `BroadcastReceiver` has called `Context.startService()` and it receives back a non-`null` `ComponentName` object, then no.  That means the `Service` was found in the system and has been "started".  Note that the start is asynchronous, so there's no guarantee that the `Service` has received its `onStartCommand()` callback before the receiver exits its `onReceive()` callback.

Also note that even though the `BroadcastReceiver` has started the `Service`, by default this has no effect on power management.  So it is possible for your `Service` to not get called back until the device is fully up and running - it could go back to sleep after your `BroadcastReceiver` finishes but before your `Service` gets to run.